# How do I quickly detect collision using a vector?

Tags: c++, collision, detection, sfml

So I'm making a tetris clone and my method for collision detection is to store a bunch of sf::FloatRects (the simplest way to collision detect using SFML) that make up each sprite on the board into a global vector, then check if the moving piece's sf::FloatRects intersect any sf::FloatRects already on the board. If they do intersect, the piece simply doesn't move. The only caveat is that I don't want to iterate through a multiple-hundred sized vector every iteration of my gameloop. Is there a more efficient way to do this? Here is some working code I have so far:

```
//the walls should have a float rect on top of sprites for coll. checking
if(wallsAdded == false){
    sf::FloatRect fr = level.GetWallTile().getGlobalBounds();
    level.GetCollisionObjects().push_back(fr);
    wallsAdded == true;
}
```

So for instance, this code takes all the sprites making up the walls on the side and floor, and stores their collision detectors (sf:FloatRect) into a global vector, which I can check if the piece is intersecting any of the elements of. I'm new to this still, so I don't know if iterating through hundreds of SFML objects just trying to find one that intersects with a sprite is bad practice or not.

Edit: Here is the for loop I'm so apprehensive about:

```
if(event.type == (sf::Event::KeyPressed)){
    switch(event.key.code){
        case sf::Keyboard::Left:{
            //std::vector<sf::FloatRect> pieceFRs_;
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                sf::FloatRect fr = level.GetGamePieces().at(temp - 1).GetPieceRectangles()[i].getGlobalBounds();
                //pieceFRs_.push_back(fr);
                for(int i = 0; i < level.GetCollisionObjects().size(); i++){
                    //get left-bound fr's, if their pos - 10 intersetcs wall, don't do anything
                    if(!fr.intersects(level.GetCollisionObjects()[i])){
                        level.GetGamePieces().at(temp - 1).MovePiece(-10, 0);
                        std::cout << "left";
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        ...
```

Comment: There are other approaches to collision detection in Tetris. Have a look at this one, where the board and falling pieces are treated like matrices: http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/implementing-tetris-collision-detection--gamedev-852

Comment: @E_net4 I like the implementation of that tutorial, using "potential" shapes to check if the actual shape will fit where it's trying to go, but I don't like the concept of dealing with a 2D matrix. Too much hardcoding for me.

Comment: What is the run-time of the loop you have written? I would keep the brute-force implementation until you have a completed prototype, and see if it causes problems. The current implementation is straight-forward and easy to change if you need to, so I would keep it until you have a stronger reason than simple apprehension.

Comment: @jburn7 I fail to understand your dislike here. You can always make some sort of abstraction over the matrices. The cool thing here is that pieces already in-place are all merged into a single collision shape.

Comment: I would consider the walls an inclusion boundary and other tiles as exclusion boundaries. Move your piece when the input says the left key is pressed for example. After your input phase, do your collision detection on its own. At that collision phase, you can move the x direction back into the walled off area and then above any pieces it may have collided with on the bottom. This will help you if you're pressing two direction keys at a time. You will still loop through all of the objects, but only once after you calculate where you want to be. Then determine where you actually are.